# How to install JpGraph

Tags: php, jpgraph

Can some one please let me know how to install and configure (JpGraph.http://jpgraph.net/doc/faq.php)

I saw the articles of that site but I cannot understand that.. Please help me..Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try out any examples.

You can download jpgraph files [here](http://jpgraph.net/download/)

The basic bar graph example is [here](http://jpgraph.net/features/src/show-example.php?target=new_bar1.php)

Comment: Ok. I found the way to do it..

1) unzip the jpgraph  files in side the www directy
2)inside the jpgraph folder we should put our code (eg <a href="http://jpgraph.net/features/src/show-example.php?target=new_bar1.php">this</a>)


just that.... :)

thanx for your help Arasu